# How can I export a Nextjs page as pdf?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, next.js, export-to-pdf

I have the following structure on a page:

```
export default function FichaTecnica(props) {
  const data = props.data;
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <TopData info={data} />
        <DataSheet datasheet={data} />
        <GraphBox history={data} />
        <MapButton hasMap={data.mapa} />
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const idIndicador = context.params.idIndicador;
  const res = await fetch(
    `${process.env.INDICADORES_BASE_URL}/indicadores/${idIndicador}`
  );

  const data = await res.json();
  if (res.status === 200) {
    return {
      props: { ...data },
    };
  } else {
    return {
      props: {
        data: [],
      },
    };
  }
}
```

Inside the custom component "" I have a a list of buttons to export the information of the page as Excel, Json, CSV and PDF. I've already done the first three buttons, but I don't know where to start to export my page as PDF.

The idea is to export it as it is, meaning that I want to have it with the same style it has with CSS and the Material UI components, for example, if the website looks like this:
[image: Website example]

The PDF file should look like that, I know I can make it a Canva and make something like Html > img > PDF but I want to allow the user to select the text of the page in the PDF.

I would really appreciate if you can give me ideas to start with!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to do this

1. An NPM Server side module - more options *potentially*
2. Client side PDF object formation, lots of challenges - client side dependencies
3. Use a service - cost

For #1 - try something like - https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme

For #2 - https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF

For #3 - https://www.htmlpdfapi.com/

Comment: I solved this via the NPM Server side option, it was more efficient and easy to implement it there. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 10):

Utilizing the [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) on the server side could be a good option.

One could create an [API in nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) to generate the PDF and pass back to the client. Something like below should be a good starting point:

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';


const saveAsPdf = async (url: string) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto(url, {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
    });

  const result = await page.pdf({
    format: 'a4',
  });
  await browser.close();

  return result;
};

export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const { url } = req.query; // pass the page to create PDF from as param

  res.setHeader(
    'Content-Disposition',
    `attachment; filename="file.pdf"`
  );
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');

  const pdf = await saveAsPdf(url as string);

  return res.send(pdf);
};
```

Note: the server has to have Chromium browser version compatible with puppeeter.

Comment: `const { url } = req.query;` What do I need to pass here? I have my component loading at localhost:3000

Comment: Is just a query string, i.e. http://localhost:3000?url=someurl, see [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#request-helpers)

Comment: please note, this won't work once deployed on vercel

Comment: @sKopheK - I've updated the answer, the server has to have a compatible Chromium version

Answer (score 0):

[Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) is definitely the best approach to go for this however I found that on larger html templates or templates that needed scrolling and needed to load images that the NextJS API route would timeout due to the duration of the request taking too long.

I ended up using https://pdfstore.dev

Disclaimer: I made it.