# How to Export a div to a formated PDF using NextJs

Tags: javascript, pdf, next.js, export

I have an app project on which we fill out forms and the information will be automatically formatted in a div to create labels (CLP labels) , so I would like to be able to export this Div in pdf format and can choose the sizes (landscape format from A5 to A8)

For this project I'm using Next.js and tailwind css.

And my question is : How to export a div in pdf format using NextJs ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this

1. An NPM Server side module - more options *potentially*
2. Client side PDF object formation, lots of challenges - client side dependencies
3. Use a service - cost

For #1 - try something like - https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf?activeTab=readme

For #2 - https://github.com/parallax/jsPDF

For #3 - https://www.htmlpdfapi.com/

From my previous post on this - [How can I export a Nextjs page as pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70931969/how-can-i-export-a-nextjs-page-as-pdf/70932567#70932567)

Comment: Thx for your response, I already see your post and try the first solution but got an error : npm ERR! code EACCES 
i will try to fix it and try again

Comment: `EACCESS` usually means `npm` does not have permissions, please post an edit if you need more help, best of luck!

Comment: This error is fixed and now I'm trying to learn how to use html-pdf ! thanks for your help !